# We ever thought before Or, We ever think before?

Tags: tense

> A - "It doesn't look the way we ever thought before"
>
> B - "It doesn't look the way we ever think before"

Thought or think: which would be correct grammatically?

Comment: Please give us more context, and also where from you got this question? Is it from a practice exercise or anything you are confused with? What you think the answer would be, and why?

Comment: In short the correct answer is "thought". But further when you ask a question,  please try to include all those information. Though there is no hard-and-fast rule that you must have to, but it will be easier for people who answer. sometimes your extra information will help them understand your question properly, or else they need to ask you for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is the good one. You are referring to the past so a past tense is required.

If you turn it into a question is looks probably easier.

- Did you ever think that it looks this way?
- Have you ever thought that it looks this way?

Answer (score 1):

The adverb *ever* is used to refer to any time in the past, present or future.

Some examples:

> Have you *ever* been to New York City? or 
>  If you *ever* need my help, just call.

In your case, the word *before* is the key! It simply applies something that happened in the past. When you refer something in the past, it takes the past tense of *think* i.e. *thought*.

So, in given two sentences, the first one is correct:

> It does not look better the way we ever *thought* before.

Just to add, you may remove a couple of words to make the sentence short and clear...

> It does not look the way we thought